# Track app downloads from Facebook and Instagram

Tags: react-native, facebook-analytics

I have some ads on my Facebook and Instragram accounts and I'd like to track these downloads.

For Facebook I guess I should install the SDK (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) but I can't fin any method to save this information. Same thing for Instragram.

If this is something we need to track when we get redirected to the store to download the app, how can check this inside the app? This is more something we need to track on Facebook/Instragram dev panel, right? Maybe here is where I'm getting confused.

Also I saw that I can create ads campaings in Facebook Ads Manager. Does it mean that I can only measure downloads using these kind of ads? What about from a link on a normal Facebook post?

I'm using React Native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `LoginManager` from the `react-native-fbsdk`.

You can use some service like `Localytics` or `Adjust` to track the events. 
You can use `Sentry` to send crash reports in case you are failing to register/login/logout. You can also use `GTM`.

Using these three services will give you a lot of power (tracking and crash reports).

Take a look at the topic `deferred deep linking facebook`, that's what you'll need if you are planning to have Ads from facebook.

[Example with Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/login/)

[Adjust](https://www.adjust.com/solutions/marketers-working-with-adjust/?utm_channel=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_term=mobile%20app%20tracking%20adjust&utm_content=noForm&utm_campaign=adjust_DT_T2C&_bt=190934581327&_bk=adjust&_bm=e&_bn=g&_bg=41965541939&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6-i-yeXW4QIVaL7tCh0sXQ9sEAAYASAAEgL4tvD_BwE)

[Localytics](https://www.localytics.com/)

[Sentry](http://sentry.io/)

[GTM](https://tagmanager.google.com/#/home)

Comment: Thanks for you help but I think that's more related with SDK events and what I need to do is move my normal posts with the link of my app to a paid Facebook ad to start tracking them.
I need the events you shared but that's already something I tried. What I don't know about that is how can I track if the user who logged in was coming from that ad. Thanks

Comment: You are very welcome. 
In that case, take a look at the topic of deeplinks, you can get the source from the external deeplink and track it.

Comment: But if I click the deeplink and I have no app installed, it will open the store to download it first, right? Which mean that maybe that user logs in after and that I won't have control over it (unless as we said the user had the app already installed)

Comment: Hm, it's not as straight forward if I understood you right. 
Correct, it will treat it as "deferred deeplink". So, you want to track where the users come from, right? If it's organic or not, right?
Maybe you can take a look at this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/3859dc64f51199de9ffd4c28db469889009075bb/js/FBAccessToken.js#L72

Comment: Hmmm, not sure to understand how that code could help on that. I think I'll lose the tracking if that user closes the app, which is understandable. I'm investigating about deep links atm and I'll do a normal tracking (without closing the app I mean). Thanks